# Zeitwerk? Ruby on Rails ::Domains::Article => /app/domains/domains/ariticle.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zeitwerk

I have domain logic code stored in

```bash
app/domains/domains/article.rb
```

The class is

```rb
class Domains::Article
end
```

It bothers me that the proper loading structure is `app/domains/domains/article.rb` and not `app/domains/article.rb`

Does anyone know what the proper directory structure and related autoload_path is?

Thank you!

-daniel

Answer (score 1):

It can be accomplished this way:

```rb
# config/initializers/autoloading.rb

module Domains
end

Rails.autoloaders.main.push_dir(
  "#{Rails.root}/app/domains",
  namespace: Domains
)

# The next additional lines are necessary in Rails < 7.1.
domains_dir = "#{Rails.root}/app/domains" # has to be a string
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths.delete(domains_dir)
Rails.application.config.watchable_dirs[domains_dir] = [:rb]
```

Comment: I setup this as above and Zeitwerk didn't want load it as described in it's documentation.

I tried 2 methods of naming the class

```
app/domains/article.rb => class ::Domains::Article & class Article
```
And Zeitwerk reported:
```
Zeitwerk@rails.main: autoload set for Article, to be loaded from Rails.root/app/domains/article.rb
Zeitwerk@rails.main: file Rails.root/app/models/article.rb is ignored because Rails.root/app/domains/article.rb has precedence
```
It appears that Zeitwerk was loading the class as ::Article regardless of the ::Domains being present or not after class.

Comment: The class should be `Domains::Article` (no need for leading double colons). Could you please share the configuration in the initializer? With that configuration, what does the log say about `app/domains/article.rb`? Is your app running Spring?